# NSURLConnection time out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I am sending a synchronous request and getting a error

```
NSData *aResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_request returningResponse:&aResponse error:&anError];

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x6ede3d0
```

What could be the reason for this? What is the default timeout for NSURLConnection? Can I print this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure you're able to connect to the URL in a browser or using a tool of some sort (e.g. curl or wget)? How about from Safari on the device (or simulator) you're testing on just to make sure it's not a network issue of some sort?

You can specify a timeout value by creating your NSURLConnection using the [requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001695-DontLinkElementID_15) class method.

Comment: Yes. I am able to fetch the data from browser. It happens very random. And time interval is set to 10 secs but I get the above mentioned error in a flash (within 1 sec).

Comment: In this case, it sounds like a server issue. Is this your server? If so, do you have access to the logs? Can you see if a request is being made?

Answer (score 0):

I think the connection is getting timed out due to the server(since error is not consistent) ... I suggest handle this error and try to send the request again ..

do a retry for 2 or 3 times with a small delay -- should help you in great level ...